# Update Text View as User Click on it

Tags: android, android-layout

I have 8 TextView in my  Linearlayout and What I am trying to achieve is  as soon as user clicks on any TextView it should get updated with the next Textview below it ...
I am trying to make simple game where Image will be randomly displayed and the user has to find that Image name from the List displayed as different 8 TextView...
eg : If there is 8 TextView with List Dog, Cat , Bike , Horse, Cow  etc.. and say Image of Cat has shown up then I want cat to disapper now every textview should get updated one row above so I can add more views at the end ...

I hope am not confusing because I am confused here ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you place all of the TextViews in an Array or a List, then it becomes simple array manipulation:

```
public void onClick(View pressed){ 
    boolean tvFound = false; //have we found the clicked tv yet?
    for(int i=0;i<mTextViews.length;i++){ //loop through all tvs
        if(pressed.getId() == mTextViews[i]){ //if this is the tv that was clicked on
            tvFound = true; 
        }
        if(tvFound){ // if we have found the tv that was clicked on
            if(i<mTextViews.length-1){ //if we arent on the last tv
                mTextViews[i].setText(mTextviews[i+1].getText()); //then replace txt with next tvs text
            }else{ //if we ARE on the last tv
                mTextViews[i].setText(""); //replace text with nothing
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also want to note that if you don't want to loop through all of the TextViews to find the one that was clicked on, you can map the ResId of each TextView to its index in the array, then you can manipulate just the necessary TextViews.

Comment: Yah I don't want to loop through all the textviews so what i will do in the above code is (pressed.getId()==R.id.TextView01) am i right ? and thanks for the help ..thanks a lot ...

Comment: I would try something like this in onClick: `switch(pressed.getId()){case R.id.TextView01: int index = 0; updateTextViews(index);break;}` Here, you are switching based on the pressed view's id. Each case knows the index (in our tv array) of that specific TextView. The index is passed to a function updateTextViews(), which will be similar to the above code, but start updating the tv array only at the passed index

Comment: ok i will try to implement this switch case and revert you back ..check if i am write .. I will go by what u said ...just implement nd show u ..check if its correct

Comment: ok, I got it so there will be 8 cases ... like case R.id.TextView02 : int index=1; updateTextViews(index); break and so on .. now this updateTextView(index){ for(int i=index;i<mTextViews.length;++i){ if(i<mTextViews-1){ mTextViews[i].setText(mTextviews[i+1].getText());}

Comment: It looks right to me. The only real way to know is to test it in your project though.